# jQuery: Do a function only once in an Ajax load

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do a simple `.fadeIn()` ONCE for the first div, but the problem is that this is an Ajax load inside a `everyTime(xxx sec)`, so it does the same thing everytime it loads again.

How can I prevent the first `div` to `.fadeIn()` over and over again, but still do this function on the new `div`?

I am not very familiar with jQuery, so feed me with a spoon :)

#### Update:

I have been trying out all of your suggestions! I really appreciate your help, but I'm still stuck. I haven't got the `.one` to work. I tried `$("#chatline:first").one(function(){ $(this).fadein()});`, but I get a major failure from jQuery :p as I said. I'm pretty new to jQuery.

I also tried adding and removing classes, but cannot make jQuery remember that the class is removed, so it fades in and out, etc.

Here's the script, sligtly shorted.

...

```
j(document).ready(function(){

   //reloads every 3sec

j(".chatref").everyTime(3000,function(i){
j.ajax({url: "chatx.php",
cache: false,
success: function(html){
j(".chatref").html(html);

   // These for testing

if($('div#chatline').hasClass('first')){
j("#chatline").fadeIn('slow');
}
```

snipped... End of jQuery

PHP (part of chatx.php):

```
div class='chatref' <- This one is only for jQuery's everytime function, e.g where to show the stuff. Don't know other ways to do this.

//First div I added classname first and hidden with PHP.

div class='chatline hidden first'

div class='chatline'

div class='chatline'
div class='chatline'

.... etc.
```

snipped... End PHP.

I hope I have explained it good enough! Thanx for the help guys!!

Comment: Showing some code would help alot

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the div to fadein on the first ajax request using [`.ajaxStop()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) if it is the first request, unbinding itself so it doesn't happen more than once, like this:

```
$("#myDiv").ajaxStop(function() {
  $(this).unbind("ajaxStop").fadeIn();
});
```

Otherwise, just bind this when actually calling the ajax loading the div so it executes when that comes back.  Alternatively, in your success function, just show it *only if it's current hidden* using the [`:hidden` selector](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/), like this:

```
$.ajax({
 //options..
 success: function(data) {
   //stuff..
   $("#myDiv:hidden").fadeIn();
 }
});
```

Comment: Hm.. didnt make much sense to me.. spoon? :D

script looks something like this:

j(".chatref").everyTime(2000,function(i){
j.ajax({url: "chat.php?",
cache: false,
success: function(html){
j(".chatref").html(html);
    
.chatref is the maindiv showing all chatlines:

so this reloads every 2sec as you can see..

Comment: @thundercat - Where's the fadeIn in that? you'd basically replace that with `j(".chatref:hidden").fadeIn();`

Answer (score 1):

There's a "one()" method in jQuery, that is similar to "bind()" but removes the event after execution. I would suggest giving it a try.

http://api.jquery.com/one/#typedatafn

Comment: Hm, i got no click function to this.. how can i use this without a click ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit how your Ajax request chain looks like. But if you know it's always the first call, you can just add a class to the div. That is, `class="fadeIn"` and remove it once it's faded in.

```
$('.fadeIn').fadeIn(function () { $(this).removeClass('fadeIn') };
```

Answer (score 1):

how about using the data store, simply set a value to true once its been shown and check before showing in future. something like...

```
if(!$('div#yourDiv').data('hasShow')){
     $('div#yourDiv').data('hasShown', true).fadeIn();
}
```

Edit-

From the code you have posted I have come up with the following;

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Hide the chat line div on load.
    $('div#chatline').hide();

    $("div#chatref").everyTime(3000,function(i){ 
        $.ajax({url: "chatx.php", cache: false, success: function(updated){
            $('div#chatref').html(updated);
            $('div#chatline').is(':hidden').fadeIn('slow');
        }});
    });
});
```

You need your PHP page to output a div as follows for the chat line.

```
<div id="chatline"></div>
```

For the chatref

```
<div id="chatref"></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why not just use `is(":hidden")`? Much simpler :)

Comment: I found that #chatline should be a class.. since its multiple lines. chatref is only wrapped around it all to display. This is fixed.

Everything i have tried here makes the first one fadein ,but when it loads again(everytime function) ,it fades in again.

The goal is to fadein the new line only once.

Comment: djizuz.. how hard could this be? :p